# What are the roots of the word endings "-frei" and "-los", and how do they differ from each other?

Tags: difference, etymology

The title basically says it all.

- Is one more "sympathetic" or "insulting" than the other?
- Is there a way of telling which is the correct form (*heimatlos* rather than *heimatfrei*, *rostfrei* rather than *rostlos*)?

(Note: my command of German is very rudimentary, so please forgive me if this question is "silly".)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Very basically, words ending in "-los" mean that something that should be there is *missing* , which is negative (at least in case the absent thing is something you would normally *like* to have...).

Words ending in "-frei" have a notion of something being *absent*, this is not necessarily a negative fact, but normally either neutral or even positive:

*wertlos* - "Wert" (Value) is missing, the thing is not worth anything

*wertfrei* - "Wert" (value) is absent, which means "unbiased", so there is no valuing bias or prejudice in a statement

*arbeitslos* - "unemployed" the possibility to work and make a living is missing

*arbeitsfrei* - "not obliged to work, free" the obligation to work on an 
"arbeitsfrei" day is absent

*zwecklos* - of no purpose - futile

*zweckfrei* - without *following* purpose - like childplay (no negative notion) or basic research without specific targets.

The notion is also used in marketing: Even if something that is *kostenlos* doesn't *cost* anything, it might also considered not to be *worth* anything. So marketing would rather say *kostenfrei*. The same applies for terms like *fettfrei*, *laktosefrei* or *frei von Schadstoffen*, which are generally preferred to the -los suffix by marketing because of their rather more positive notion.

The above applies to words that occur with both suffixes. There are, however, quite a number of words that would only occur with one of them. For this class of words, I would rather not say "positive" or "negative" - Here both -los and -frei suffixes would simply denote "not there".

Examples:

- *grenzenlos* - limitless
- *schadlos* - free of (mainly financial) damage, but
- *schadensfrei* - without any (mainly physical) damage
- *endlos* - without end

Comment: Thank you -- that's very clear and helpful. I'll wait a couple of days for "competing answers" before accepting.

Comment: Good answer, though *-los* words aren't always negative in meaning but negating the original meaning. For example *schadlos* means *without any harm*, which is positive. Same with *vorurteilslos*, *konfliktlos* etc. And then there are words that are just stating a fact, without a judgement e.g. *endlos*, *randlos*, *grenzenlos*, *zeitlos*.

Comment: @Janka Most of your examples don't have a *-frei* counterpart. Hard to point out a difference, then.

Comment: @user135711: Die hier behandelten Wörter, die mit *-los* oder *-frei* enden, sind Adjektive. Aber »loswerden« ist ein Verb (ein anderes Verb wäre »freikaufen«), und diese Verben sind trennbare Verben.

Comment: @user135711: Kommentare sind nicht der richtige Ort um Fragen zu stellen. Bitte verfasse eine eigene Frage: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: Good explanation - and I think it even extends to *sinnfrei* vs. *sinnlos*. While negative, something that is *sinnfrei* is so nonsensical that there isn't even any reasonable *Sinn* that is missing.

Answer (score 4):

I think the harsh truth is that you have to learn each of them as a separate lexicon entry.

The roots of -los and -frei share the same mental image, so it's difficult to use that to distinguish them from each other:

- **-los** comes from the same root as *loose* (*lausaz)
- **-frei** comes from the same root as *free* (*frijaz)

In both cases, something is separated from something else, metaphorically speaking. Semantically, it makes the same sense to say that something is *rostlos* (~loose from rust/rust-less) than to say it is *rostfrei* (~free from rust/rust-free). My guess is that 90% of the reason why *rostfrei* is the one used (even though *rostlos* isn't wrong and would be well understood to mean the same thing!) is that it is much easier to distinguish from the similar sounding *rastlos* (restless). That and the marketing factor tofro mentioned. "Freedom" is always a good association with your product, isn't it.

In some cases, both variations might be used frequently for the same meaning. For example, *sinnlos* and *sinnfrei* are pretty much synonyms. In others, both have a distinct meaning and mixing them up would sound very weird to the native speaker. Or one of them won't be used at all. Why is there no *endfrei*, for example? I can't give you a reason. You have to memorize it like this.

Comment: "much easier to distinguish from the similar sounding *rastlos* (restless)" - I keep seeing *trostlos* (bleak, desolate) whenever I read *rostlos*.

Answer (score 3):

As @annatar sais *-los* is not always negative and can even be positive, like *kostenlos* (probably most adverts do still stick to this more common word), *mühelos* (hassle-free). If no such word is dominantly used, adverts do tend to use words like *zuckerfrei* (), *glutenfrei*, *tierversuchsfrei*, …

However, it does seem like **if something does have a negative (needy or somewhat disrespecting) connotation, it’s always *-los* (and not *-frei*)**.

- signifying need: *arbeitslos* (unemployed), *obdachlos* (homeless), *mittellos* (fundless)
- signifying disrespect: *sittenlos* (immoral), *wertlos* (worthless), *ahnungslos* (clueless)

*sinnlos* is also harsher than *sinnfrei*, though the latter is colloquially also used for pointlessness (besides for non-evaluation).

For neologism (possibly) originating from English, it seems *-less* is mostly translated to *-los* (also *-free* fairly commonly translated to *-frei*):

- *schnurlos* (wireless), *papierlos* (paperless), *verbindungslos* (connectionless)
- *verkehrsfrei* (vehicle-free), *emissionsfrei* (emission-free), *torsionsfrei* (torsion-free)

Answer (score 1):

X-los means *lacking* a good thing. That's "bad."

Y-frei means *free* of a bad thing. That's "good."

Examples:

Arbeitslos. Literally "work-less," not having work, in the sense of being unemployed. (Bad.)

Arbeitsfrei. Literally "work-free," not having work, in the sense of being retired or having leisure. (OK, maybe even good.)

Einwandfrei. Literally "objection-free" or "clean." (Good).

You select the use by the context. For instance, "Heimat" is something most people want, so it makes sense that being "heimatlos" (homeless) is a bad thing. On the other hand, almost no one (except for maybe "flower children" of the 1960s) would argue that running away from home without finding another one is a good thing, and that one wants to be "heimatfrei."

The terms employ "reverse" psychology. An example of this is "The enemy of my enemy is my friend."

Comment: See Jankas comment at tofros answer, about *schadlos* etc. I like to add *parteilos*.